# How do I solve AdjustCapsLockLEDForKeyTransitionHandling?

Tags: java, keylistener, keyevent

I am trying to use `KeyListener` to input information, such as using the arrow keys to move an object in a plane, but as soon as I press my first key, the error below is thrown:

`2021-05-20 09:55:35.400 java[36269:3330310] TSM AdjustCapsLockLEDForKeyTransitionHandling - _ISSetPhysicalKeyboardCapsLockLED Inhibit`

My code is like this:

```
    KeyListener listener = new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            int key = e.getKeyCode();
            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_KP_UP) {
                if (x != 5) {
                    x -= 10;
                    repaint();
                }
            }
            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_KP_RIGHT){
                if (x != 495) {
                    x += 10;
                    repaint();
                }
            }
            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_KP_DOWN) {
                if (y != 375) {
                    y += 10;
                    repaint();
                }
            }
            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_KP_UP) {
                if (y != 5) {
                    y -= 10;
                    repaint();
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Everything in this code works properly. I am using a 2019 MacBook 16-inch. I am implementing codes on Eclipse. Is there any way that this problem can be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Change your keyboard Hotkey at Preference/Keyboard/HotKey/input method
If your first key is CapLock, the error will show.
Change the input method HotKey will solve.

Comment: In Mac BigSur, that would be Preferences ->  Keyboard -> Input Sources. There, unselect the "use the Caps Lock key..." option at the bottom