# Java TSM AdjustCapsLockLEDForKeyTransitionHandling

Tags: java, swing, awt, keylistener, keyevent

I am trying to capture up,down,right,left keys from `KeyEvent`, and I am getting following message when I press a key:

> 2021-06-05 00:46:11.176 java[47646:1823153] TSM AdjustCapsLockLEDForKeyTransitionHandling - _ISSetPhysicalKeyboardCapsLockLED Inhibit

This is my code:

Character.java

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;


public class Character {
    private int dx;
    private int dy;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private String imageLocation;
    private Image image;
    private boolean moveable;
    
    public Character(int x, int y, String imgLoc, boolean m){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        imageLocation = imgLoc;
        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(imageLocation));
        image = ii.getImage();
        moveable = m;
    }

    public void move() {
        if(moveable){
            x += dx;
            y += dy;
        }
    }

    public boolean moveable(){
        return moveable;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public Image getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void keyPresed(KeyEvent e){
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            System.out.println("left key pressed");
            dx = -1;
        }
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            dx = 1;
        }
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            dy = -1;
        }
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
            dy = 1;
        }
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            dx = 0;
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            dx = 0;
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            dy = 0;
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            dy = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

** ADDED: **

Lounge.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Lounge extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    private Timer timer;
    private Player player;
    
    public Lounge(){
       //addKeyListener(new TAdapter());
        setFocusable(true);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setDoubleBuffered(true);

        player = new Player(1000, 40);

        timer = new Timer(5, this);
        timer.start();
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.drawImage(player.getImage(), player.getX(), player.getY(), this);

        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
        g.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        player.move();
        repaint();
    }
    
    private class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter{
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
            player.keyReleased(e);
        }
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
            player.keyReleased(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main extends JFrame{
    public Main(){
        add(new Lounge());

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(1280,720);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setTitle("Be My Guest");
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
}
```

I am using Visual Studio Code on MacBook pro 2017

Please help me!

Comment: I don't see any logging statements that aligns with the log/output that you provided.

Comment: Sorry! I didn't upload other classes.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the Caps-Lock key being pressed initially, I found a similar question over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67613071/how-do-i-solve-adjustcapslockledforkeytransitionhandling)

Another problem I found is that The method `keyPressed` is spelt wrongly as `keyPresed` that may cause some issues also